# Simple Drag and Drop in WebAssembly

Tags: drag-and-drop, blazor, draggable, blazor-webassembly

I wish to add the ability to sense a drag event in my Blazor WebAssembly component.  What I want is really simple (I thought).  I don't need to actually drop the item, I just need to sense the id name of the div where the user clicked their mouse down, and then sense the id name of the div where the user lifted the left mouse button.

I wish to actually then re-render the component after doing some server-side database actions.  I would think this is so simple, but after 2 days of reading Chris Sanity's post and dozens of other... the only workable code I can get to run is below.  The problem is that the draggedItemId comes back as an integer and not 'myDraggableDiv'

Any help welcome!

```
@page "/"

<div draggable="true" id="myDraggableDiv" @ondragstart="HandleDragStart" @ref="draggedElement">Drag me!</div>

@code {
    
    private ElementReference draggedElement;
    private string draggedItemId;

    private void HandleDragStart(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        draggedItemId = draggedElement.Id;
        Console.WriteLine(draggedItemId);
    }
}
```

HERE IS THE NEW CODE I CREATED WITH YOUR HELPFUL SUGGESTION

```
@page "/"

<div draggable="true" id="myDraggableDiv1"
     style="border-color: black;border-style:solid;"
     @ondragend="@(e => HandleDragEnd(e, "End1"))"
     @ondragstart="@(e => HandleDragStart(e, "Start1"))"
     @ondrop="@(e=> HandleDrop(e, "Drop1"))"
     @ondragenter="@(e=> HandleDragEnter(e, "Enter1"))"
     @ondragleave="@(e=> HandleDragLeave(e, "Leave1"))"
     >
    Drag me 1!
</div>
<div draggable="true" id="myDraggableDiv2" 
     style="border-color: black;border-style:solid;"
     @ondragend="@(e => HandleDragEnd(e, "End2"))"
     @ondragstart="@(e => HandleDragStart(e, "Start2"))"
     @ondrop="@(e=> HandleDrop(e, "Drop2"))"
     @ondragenter="@(e=> HandleDragEnter(e, "Enter2"))"
     @ondragleave="@(e=> HandleDragLeave(e, "Leave2"))"
     >
    Drag me 2!
</div>
@code {
    string _leftEntered = "";

    private void HandleDragStart(DragEventArgs e,string id)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(id);
    }
    private void HandleDragEnd(DragEventArgs e,string id)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ending drag from"+id+"  _lastEntered="+ _leftEntered);
    }
    private void HandleDrop(DragEventArgs e, string id)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(id);
    }
    private void HandleDragEnter(DragEventArgs e, string id)
    {
        _leftEntered = id;
        Console.WriteLine("_lastEntered now = "+id);
    }
    private void HandleDragLeave(DragEventArgs e, string id)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(id);
    }
}
'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ElementReference.Id` does not give you the id attribute of the html element.

You can use `@ondragstart="@(e => HandleDragStart(e, "myDraggableDiv"))"`

```
private void HandleDragStart(DragEventArgs e, string id)
{
    draggedItemId = id;
    Console.WriteLine(draggedItemId);
}
```

Comment: So helpful!!!!   Is the code I have now added to my question a good way to implement this or is there a more elegant, better way?